# NTFS4DOS without logo?

Tags: boot, ntfs, ms-dos, disk-image, ntfs4dos

I want to create NTFS bootable image. I use NTFS4DOS for read/write access to NTFS partitions. I use it because it loads fast, in just a few seconds. Every time I load from it, the NTFS4DOS logo appears, and I must type `YES`.  I'd like to hide the logo and/or run it without entering `YES` every time.

Is there any tool which can send input (send `YES`) to it?
Are there any versions which are hidden or don't require it?
Also, suggestions for other tools/drivers which can access NTFS drives will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ever hear of Windows AIK?
Any current Linux bootable livecd or USB (Will load faster than AIK)

`echo YES|ntfs4dos`
(might work)
  Lets pretend you have access to the drive then what do you want to do?

Comment: @cybernard Thanks for info. I know WAIK, and bootable LiveCDs, USBs. But I'd prefer NTFS4DOS, because DOS with Ntfs4Dos loads faster than anything else (or maybe some linuxoids can be faster).

Comment: you would have to have a threaded program to run ntfs4dos in 1 thread and then use thread 2 to echo YES to thread 1.  5 years ago I could have told you how to do this, but now I have forgotten it.  Depending on the hardware a linux distro could come close.  Try http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/  they have  8mb and 12mb version. If the ntfs modules is not included it can be added with minimal overhead.

Comment: @cybernard thanks. Thanks for very good infos. If your ways are working, write an 'answer' and I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: I Tried "echo ...|..." in MS-DOS 6, 7, 8- did NOT help. (but works well in Win7's Command Prompt)